# Unable to delete file, although the file identifier has been closed [WinError 32]

Tags: python, python-3.x, permissions, file-permissions

I have a couple of textfiles, that I don't need after reading their contents. For this, I use:

```
with open('MyData.txt') as f:
    ...
f.close()                         # same problem, with or without close()
os.remove('MyData.txt')
```

This results in *PermissionError: [WinError 32]*, telling me that the file is still being used in another process.
Reading up on this, I thought that `with open(...) as f:` would already close the file identifier, which I originally thought to be the problem. But with or without adding `f.close()` at the end, I get this error.

---

*Disclaimer: DON'T KNOW IF THIS IS IMPORTANT:*
I am using the *matlab_engine* module, where I import the text file and extract further information. I stop the matlab engine before trying to delete the files though..

*Info:*
Using Python 3.6 on Windows 10

Comment: Are you sure it's your porcess using the file? (File explorer might tell you). How is the matlab negine using the file? You haven't shown that

Comment: Yes, `with open(...) as f:` will close `f` as soon as you leave the `with` block, but calling `f.close()` on a closed file is harmless.

Comment: Hey @doctorlove, thanks for pointing me towards MATLAB again! Inside MATLAB I was able to delete the files without any problem, so I figured (too fast) it must've been some Python problem. I explicitly closed the matlab engine before trying to delete the files, but the problem would remain.

Now I went back in and realized, that the thing I did in Python (closing the file ID) twice by using the `close()` was actually missing in my MATLAB script.. 

Now it works! 
Although I was certain that all pointers towards files from matlab were deleted when stopping the matlab engine from running...